# TD width more than designated

Tags: html, asp.net, css, web

I have a table as below

```
    <table style="border-spacing: 10px; width:auto; table-layout: fixed" id="tblCustomerinput">
       <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="2px">
                   <span class="error"> *</span>
                 </td>
                 <td style="width: auto;resize: horizontal;">
                    <span>Required Field</span>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <span id="cvEventsValidator" class="error" style="display:none;">Please complete the required fields below.</span>
                      <span id="reqFieldValidator" class="error" style="color:Red;display:none;">Please complete the required fields below.</span>
<br>

                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width="2px">

                </td>
                <td width="130px">
                  <b> <span id="lblCustNumber">Customer Number:</span></b>  
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <input name="txtCustNumber" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtCustNumber"> 
                 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td width="2px"><span class="error">*</span>
                   </td>
                   <td width="130px">
                      <b> <span id="lblFirstName">First Name:</span>  </b>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input name="txtFirstName" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtFirstName" class="requiredfield">
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width="2px"><span class="error">*</span>
                    </td>
                    <td width="130px">
                                        <b> <span id="lblLastName">Last Name:</span></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="txtLastName" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtLastName" class="requiredfield">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="2px">

                    </td>
                  <td width="130px">
                    <b> <span id="lblCompanyName">Company Name:</span></b>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input name="txtCompanyName" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtCompanyName">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td width="2px" span="" class="error">*
                   </td>
                   <td width="130px">
                                       <b>  <span id="lblPhoneNumber">Phone Number:</span></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input name="txtPhoneNumber" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtPhoneNumber" class="requiredfield">
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td width="2px"><span class="error">*</span>
                      </td>
                      <td width="130px"><b>
                         <span id="lblEmail">E-mail Address:</span></b>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                           <input name="txtEmail" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtEmail" class="requiredfield">
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td width="2px">

                      </td>
                      <td width="130px">
                          <b> <span id="lblDynamicField" maxlength="50"></span></b>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input name="txtDynamicField" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtDynamicField">
                      </td>
                    </tr>                                              
                    <tr>
                       <td colspan="2"><span id="Label1">Comments:</span> &nbsp;
                                     <br>

                          <textarea name="txtComment" rows="5" cols="20" id="txtComment" class="feedback_comment" onkeypress="return this.value.length &lt;=1500" onkeydown="limitText(this,1500);" onkeyup="limitText(this,1500);" style="width:360px;" clicks="0" onfocus="clearContents(this);">Please describe the problem you found...</textarea></td>
                     </tr>
                 </tbody>
         </table>
```

The width of the second  always comes out as 347px for reasons I cant quite comprehend(!!??)
I set a fixed width for the td as 130 px.
Could anyone help me with this please? I had been scratching my head till it aches for this :)
Basically I need to line up the Labels closer to the Textboxes.

As always thanks a ton for your help in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default width of the textarea which spans the first and second column is larger than the 130px. You need to set the width of the textarea to 130px or smaller. Or you can span the textarea's parent td colspan to 3 columns instead of 2.

Comment: Setting `colspan=3` is surely better than making the textarea just 130px wide. Alternatively, move the textarea and its label out of the table; they don’t really belong to the tabular structure (which has a column for requiredness marker, a column for a label, and a column for a control – it fitted into that structure, the current last row should have empty first cell, “Comments” in the second cell, and the textarea in the third cell.